# Excel VBA formula throws "#Name!"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My `Sub createTrip()` creates a new worksheet and a table within it.

It works basically fine, but I use this one function for all the data range cells. The function calculates distances between coordinates in the top rows and the left rows.
The function itself has **no mistakes**:

```
=ARCCOS(SIN(E$3*PI()/180)*SIN($C5*PI()/180)+COS(E$3*PI()/180)*COS($C5*PI()/180)*COS(($D5*PI()/180)-(E$4*PI()/180)))*6367.4445
```

(I also tried to add the Worksheets name to it like `=ARCCOS(SIN(Processing!E$3*PI()/1...` - without any success.)

The problem is, when my sub is done, there will be a `#NAME`-error in all the data range cells.
**The error will be removed by clicking into the cell, clicking into the formula-bar and clicking back onto the worksheet - without changing anything.**
I tried to add some recalculation lines to my sub, but that does not help:

```vb
ws.EnableCalculation = False
ws.EnableCalculation = True
```

What else can I do?

The formula is applied to the cells with VBA like this:

```vb
Dim Pro As Worksheet
Set Pro = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processing")

' start for loop (ii)
' if maximum ii is reached:
With Pro
    Set distanceRange = .Range(.Cells(5, 5), .Cells(ii + 6, ii + 6))
End With

distanceRange.Select
distanceRange.Formula = "=ARCCOS(SIN(E$3*PI()/180)*SIN($C5*PI()/180)+COS(E$3*PI()/180)*COS($C5*PI()/180)*COS(($D5*PI()/180)-(E$4*PI()/180)))*6367.4445"
```

Thanks for helping here!

Comment: Which version you are using? I am using 2013 and the function ARCCOS is not available. #NAME? errors only occurs when you input a function which is either misspelled of not available with the version you are using.

Comment: well, thanks. it's supposed to be a... "dot". like 1.5 (one and a half) - it only works with a dot. thanks for checking, but i already sorted that out before. the #Name error remains.

Comment: Should `ARCCOS` be `ACOS`?

Comment: I am using Excel 2016 - no idea about the VBA version. I just tried ACOS instead of ARCCOS, but it does not work, still.

Comment: I'm on xl2016 as well and there is no ARCCOS function. Just `ACOS` and `ACOSH`.

Comment: THANK YOU! Got the solution guys ... In my code, I used another function just before the arccos. The ROUND-function. I wrote the german one.. "RUNDEN". Since it does not matter in excel. It obviously does in VBA.

Comment: @Jeeped, your right i guess. it works with ROUND(ACOS()), now :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought you may be playing around with foreign language functions (which was why I marked as duplicate earlier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ACOS` not `ARCCOS`

`=ACOS(SIN(E$3*PI()/180)*SIN($C5*PI()/180)+COS(E$3*PI()/180)*COS($C5*PI()/180)*COS(($D5*PI()/180)-(E$4*PI()/180)))*6367.4445`

Comment: Might also be worthwhile to note the use of the EN-US style `6367.4445` instead of `6367,4445`.

Comment: Next time you get #NAME as a formula result, go to the Formula tab on the ribbon, then under the Formula Auditing group, click Evaluate Formula. You can then click Evaluate until you hit the issue. In your case, the first click reveals the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is working with the exact same formula of Excel **if** Excel language is set to a different language from English.

In VBA we must write the formulas in English. (Spanish example):

Application.Range("'Hoja1'!T3").Formula = "=MODA(O8:O" & row_set & ")" `Throw #Name error`

> Changing from "MODA" function in Spanish to "MODE" function in English

Application.Range("'Hoja1'!T3").Formula = "=MODE(O8:O" & row_set & ")" `Work as expected`

Try this [tool](http://dolf.trieschnigg.nl/excel/index.php) for function translate

Comment: You saved my day.. figuring out that you need english in vba.. omg. Never thought about that, but makes sense now and most important, works. Thanks bud!

Comment: thanks, save my day ! By the way the formula in English uses "," and in French uses ";"

Comment: `.Formula` always expects the formula in en-us. `.FormulaLocal` always expects the formula in the language of the Excel installation. You can use either from VBA, so the "In VBA we must write the formulas in English" is also not correct.

Answer (score -2):

In VBA code use english name of formula.
It works.

Comment: If you supply it to `.Formula`. And if you supply it to `.FormulaLocal`, it doesn't.